# Does Clojure require a JDK?

Tags: clojure

I want to distribute a Clojure program. Do I need a JDK or can a JRE handle everything in Clojure?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You only need the user to have a JRE (v1.5 or above)

Clojure programs can be compiled into a jar file. You don't have to use something like 
leiningen, but it's a lot easier.

Check out this [page](http://clojure.org/compilation) on the Clojure.org site for how to compile and run a program.

You can compile to a jar file from the REPL:

```
(compile 'clojure.examples.hello)
```

Here's how you would run a compile jar:

```
java -cp ./classes:clojure.jar clojure.examples.instance asdf
```

Comment: And will the Clojure "eval" command still work, even without a JDK? I don't understand how it could compile without a JDK

Comment: That's a good question. I *think* the answer is that the Clojure jar includes code that compiles Clojure to Java bytecode and does not use javac.

Comment: Pretty much yes. Here's the body of `eval`: `(. clojure.lang.Compiler (eval form)))`.

Comment: Technically, you don't need to even compile the clojure program into a jar file, right? Including the clojure jar and a simple shell script to run it (for convenience) should be sufficient.

Answer (score 6):

You just need a JRE.

https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/TUTORIAL.md explains in more detail, but I believe you just want an "Uberjar" which will contain all the dependencies that you need to distribute your application.

Answer (score -3):

JRE is required! You can easily download it from Internet.